# How to implement raytracing with VAOs

Tags: opengl, shader

Lets say i have a single VAO creating a chess-board.

Its made up of normals, vertices and indices using a simple shader which colors the board alternating by using the modulo function on the coordinates...

How would I implement picking?

I found out from other threads here that raytracing is the way to go, but thats where i struggle really hard to implement.

Data is made of Vector3 for the vertices and normals, uint for the indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you implement a ray intersection approach, then having a VAO, or VBO is completely irrelevant, because you're not going to use OpenGL for this. You do the math manually and on the CPU.

Comment: Long story short, i want to draw a greem frame around the tile, my mouse is over. Since im not usind 2D there is a certain changable perspective. What i understand so far is, that http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm returns me Hits using names again, but what do i need to do to create the green frame around the tile? Since is all stored in a single VAO how do i know where the green frame nees to be? Or can i retrieve a XYZ of the intersection?

Comment: It's *not* all stored on the VAO, you keep a copy in ordinary memory as well and ray pick from there using a CPU algorithm and usually (if it's a lot of data) a 3D space partitioning scheme. You then either *add* extra geometry to draw the greem(?) frame, or *modify* the contents of the VAO to trigger a different frame color in your shader. All depends on your implementation, but first you should focus on getting the picking right.

Comment: @CSharpie: The selection mode you're referring to is poorly supported by most OpenGL implementations and extremely slow. Also it's not raytesting, but merely tests if drawing commands would result to produce output in a given area of the screen. Here's some good advice: **Stay clear of OpenGL selection mode!**

Comment: Well thank you guys, i guess this is enough input i will need to be occupied a few days.